# I want to see who pressed the button in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently studied the buttons, and I can't figure out how to get the user who clicked on the interaction button in discord.py

Here is my code:

```
class NewView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @button(label='First Button', custom_id='button_one', style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def buttonone(self, button: Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello, {button.author.display_name}")



@bot.command()
async def callbutton(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send('Your Button:', view=NewView())
```

Comment: You should have a look at [this example on github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/confirm.py).

Comment: `interaction.author`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `.user` attribute to extract the user who sent that interaction:

[Interactions API Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction#discord.Interaction.user)
[Discord Developer Portal - Documentation - Interaction](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#interaction-object)

Answer (score 0):

In your button decorator you can do `print(interaction.user)` and it will print user and tag of user that pushed it. if you want there id you can do print(interaction.user.id)